# Looking for a regex to match if specific statement doesn't exist

Tags: regex, perl

I have few perl statements that i need to match/mismatch against a regular expression.

the statements are:

```
$variable_A{<default>} = $abcd if ($address_space{$key_A}<=$address);  <-- mismatch as 'if' exist at end of statement

$variable_B{<default>} = $abcd;              <-- match
```

i have tried the following:

`(\$[a-zA-Z\${}_.\'\"\/() <>]+)\s*=\s*([0-9a-zA-Z\${}_\+\-\'\"()]+)(?!if)`

but this regexp match both cases...

i know there are positive and negative lookahead (match if condition is met), but it seems i don't understand how to use them..

[Here is a DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dR4bN1/9)

Comment: The regex doesn't actually match the first case because it can't match spaces after `$abcd`. Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Also, should the match fail if an `if` occurs anywhere on the line or just right after the variable? Right now, the regex `\$[a-zA-Z_{}<>()\$]+\s*=\s*\$[$a-z{}<>()]+;` would be enough to exclude the first case, simply because of the `;` that isn't present after `$abcd`...

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Hi Tim, no shortcuts :), i've pasted the real test case (full) - previously tried to simplify it

Comment: Your new test case also matches the expression within parentheses (and rightly so, according to the current rules, since no `if` follows that expression). What would be the rule that disallows that match?

Comment: This is pretty much impossible to do in general using regular expressions. You might want to look at the [PPI](http://metacpan.org/module/PPI)
 module *"Parse, Analyze and Manipulate Perl (without perl)"*